# Which sacraments can an intersex individual receive in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments, intersex

Which sacraments can an intersex individual receive in the Catholic Church?

Comment: By "intersex" do you mean "exhibiting physical characteristics of both sexes"?

Comment: Yes, physical and/or chemical

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Hermaphrodites can be baptized.

Regarding [1917 Canon 748](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=PA277) (which has no equivalent in the 1983 Code), which deals with baptism in the case of deformed or abnormal fetal humans, canonist Charles Augustine, O.S.B., D.D., writes in [*A Commentary on the New Code of Canon Law*, on Can. 748](https://archive.org/stream/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary#page/n1371/mode/2up):

> There is no difficulty as to hermaphrodites, because sex does not affect the validity of Baptism.

## Complete hermaphrodites cannot be validly ordained.

[Dom Augustine wrote](https://archive.org/stream/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary#page/n1763/mode/2up) on [1917 Can. 968](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=PA336) (= [1983 Canon 1024](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3P.HTM)):

> Concerning *hermaphrodites*, it must be said that complete hermaphrodites, whose sex cannot be determined, may not be validly ordained; whereas those with whom the male sex prevails may be ordained validly but not licitly.

## Complete hermaphrodites cannot validly marry.

[Dom Augustine wrote](https://archive.org/stream/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary#page/n2082/mode/2up) on [1917 Can. 1068](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=PA368) (= [1983 Canon 1084](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3Y.HTM)), which deals with sexual impotence, an impediment to the valid reception of the sacrament of marriage:

> As to *hermaphrodites*, or such persons as have the sexual characteristics of both sexes, whether it be *androgynia* or *gynandria* or *hermaphroditismus neuter*, the testimony of physicians is required [to determine whether they are sexually impotent or not]. No *hermaphroditus neuter* can possibly be called capable of marrying because the sex is not sufficiently determined.

<sup>*androgynia* = hermaphroditic with male aspect predominant

*gynandria* = hermaphroditic with female aspect predominant

*hermaphroditus neuter* = a complete hermaphrodite (equal male and female aspects)</sup>

---

There are no other canons explicitly forbidding hermaphrodites *qua* hermaphrodites from receiving the other sacraments (Confirmation, Eucharist, Penance, Extreme Unction).

Comment: The 1917 Code was voided by the 1983 Code.

Comment: Was it completely abrogated?

Comment: The 1917 Code of Canon Law was abrogated by the 1983 Code, but the new Code lists some loopholes: Can. 6 §1. When this Code takes force, the following are abrogated:
  1º the Code of Canon Law promulgated in 1917;
  2º other universal or particular laws contrary to the prescripts of this Code unless other provision is expressly made for particular laws;
  3º any universal or particular penal laws whatsoever issued by the Apostolic See;
  §2. **Insofar as they repeat former law, the canons of this Code must be assessed also in accord with canonical tradition.**